# How to count users from last 7, 15, 30 dyas ago (from sysdate) Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

So, I am trying to count my users who login 7,15, & 30 days ago from sysdate. I know I can count users who loged in 7 days ago and I can group them, but I would like to count users who loged in 7, 15, & 30 days ago.

```
select roel, count(column_name)
FROM  USER , STRUCTURE
where login_time > sysdate - 7
group by role
```

I would like to get the results below:

```
Role    7days ago    15 days ago    30 days ago    Never 
Admin   1            20             0              150
```

Comment: You do realise that you're doing a `CROSS JOIN` between `USER` and `STRUCTURE` right?  This surely can't be your intent.

Comment: I would like to get my result like

Role-------7days ago -----15 days ago -----30 days ago-------Never
Admin----------1-----------------20---------------------0------------------150

Thank you once again

Comment: You are missing the point.  A cross join is not going to give you useful information.  Please edit your question and show sample data from the tables.

Comment: I had to join my table because my users are in users table and role are in role table. Also Users table contain the login time. and I need to know which role users login 7, 15 & 30 days ago. hope that make sense.

Comment: @Palash - your query as written is a cross join (google it) without restriction, which will create a huge number of nonsensical rows. It will not produce what you are after. You are looking for either an inner join (assuming each user must have a role) or an outer join oriented to the user table (if roles are not required).

Comment: From you comment to @Gordon Linnoff answer it is not perceptible from your question what you want to do. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, so here's what I want 

I have 2 tables, named "Role" & "Structure"

"Role" table has my users information including last login time, and my "Structure" table has my users role information including other information

Now, I would like to see how many users login in last 7, 15 & 30 days ago from my system date. and I would like to see my results Like
Role    7days ago    15 days ago    30 days ago    Never 
Admin         1                 20                     0              150

Comment: Interesting that the users role information is in structure, not in role....? anyway, given what you have said, just take the suggestion by @GordonLinoff and modify it to join in the structure table to obtain that role column. So, something like this: "select s.role, .... from role r join structure s on r.userid = s.userid group by s.role". To see what this does differently from your approach, and the importance of that difference, you should read up on JOINs and how each type of join is different. Yours is a cross join, my suggestion is an inner join.

Comment: But Gordon Linoff post shows that Gordon Linoff did sum not count and Gordon Linoff  sum login_time which is not correct either. I can do inner join like s.role.

Comment: He did sum because every time the WHEN clause comes back true it returns 1, which is then collected into the sum aggregation. This accomplishes the same thing as count would (and is probably more efficient).

His answer is not incorrect. Study it more thoroughly and it will be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count users, the basic idea is conditional aggregation.  Assuming that `login_time` and `sysdate` are both in the `user` table, you can do:

```
select role,
       sum(case when login_time > sysdate - 7 then 1 else 0 end) as count_07,
       sum(case when login_time > sysdate - 15 then 1 else 0 end) as count_15,
       sum(case when login_time > sysdate - 30 then 1 else 0 end) as count_30
from user u
group by role;
```

Why you are doing a Cartesian product between `user` and `structure` is unclear.  Perhaps a join is actually needed for the data you have.

Also, it is unusual to use `sysdate` for this purpose, because `sysdate` has a time component.  Normally, you just want to look at the dates.

Comment: You can user TRUNC(SYSDATE) to get just the date portion

Comment: I had to join my table because my users are in users table and role are in role table. Also Users table contain the login time. and I need to know which role users login 7, 15 & 30 days ago

Comment: @Palash . . . You should edit the question and clarify what the data looks like.